# Calculating acceleration function for given time, distance, initial velocity

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

An object has an initial velocity of **v** and should stop in **d** meters, in **t** seconds where **v*t >= d**. I can predict that this acceleration won't be constant but it is a function of time and this problem may not have one exact solution for given **v**, **t** and **d**. But I am not able to think of any solution, can any one help me to calculate this function?

Comment: In a question like this typically the form of the acceleration is decided based on the physical properties examined.For example acceleration may be a result of some motor power output, or a spring/damper reaction or a field force like gravity or electrostatics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $v-t$    graph is quadratic; we can write velocity, acceleration and distance functions as

$$ f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c              \mbox{       } (\mathrm{velocity})$$

$$f'(x) = 2ax + b                   \mbox{       } (\mathrm{acceleration})   $$

$$   F(x) = ax^3/3 + bx^2/2 + cx + k   \mbox{       } (\mathrm{distance})    $$

From given requirement, we know that initial velocity is $v$ where $t=0$. Then:

$$   f(0) = v$$

$$c = v $$

Again from given requirement, we know that $v=0$ where $t=t$.

$$f(t) = 0$$

$$    at^2 + bt + c = 0$$

We also know that all movement will complete in a distance of $d$.       So integral from $0$ to $t$ should result $d$.

$$       d = F(t) - F(0)$$

From here we can calculate that

$$    b = (6d - 4vt) / t^2$$

$$    a = -(((6d - 4vt) / t^2)t + v) / t^2$$

Now we can write $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ in terms of given $v$, $t$ and $d$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the function is unique.

Consider the following velocity-time graph, where the initial velocity is $v$ and time taken to stop is $t$,

[image: velocity-time graph]

Now, the area under the curve represents the distance traveled $d$. I hardly think that there is a unique curve which gives you the area equal to $d$. After all, your only constraints are the initial and final point of the curve.

Please think about it, and if I'm wrong, feel great while down-voting this answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This was what I meant by "this problem may not have one exact solution for given v, t and d"

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration may be given as a function of distance/displacement $a(x)$ or as a function of speed $a(v)$, or both $a(x,v)$.

In the later case, a numerical scheme is generally needed to solve for $a(t)$.

### Case 1

When considering $a(x)$ then $$a(x)\, {\rm d} x = \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}t}\,{\rm d} x = 
\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t}\,{\rm d} v = v\, {\rm d} v $$

$$ \int a(x)\, {\rm d} x = \frac{1}{2} v^2 + K_1 $$
$$ u = \sqrt{2 \left(  \int a(x)\, {\rm d} x - K_1 \right) } $$

This resuts in a function $u(x)$ given some initial conditions for $u$ and $x$ to find $K_1$.

Then you have $$ t= \int \frac{1}{u(x)}\,{\rm d} x + K_2 $$

This results in a function $x(t)$ given some initial conditions for $x$ and $t$ to find $K_2$

### Case 2

When considering $a(u)$ then
  $$ \frac{1}{a(u)}\,{\rm d}u = \frac{{\rm d} t}{{\rm d} u} \,{\rm d}u = \,{\rm d}t$$

$$ t = \int \frac{1}{a(u)}\,{\rm d}u + K_1 $$

which is solved for $u(t)$ given some initial conditions for $u$ and $t$ solving for $K_1$

Also you can use

$$ \frac{u}{a(u)}\,{\rm d}u = \frac{u {\rm d} t}{{\rm d} u} \,{\rm d}u = {\rm d} x $$

$$ x = \int \frac{u}{a(u)}\,{\rm d}u + K_2 $$

which is solved for $u(x)$ given some initial conditions for $u$ and $x$ solving for $K_2$